# How to print a message when a user closes Windows calculator?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have a program in java. The program opens Windows calculator with Runtime.exec. So far so good, but I need that when program is closed by a user, a message appears saying "Program has been closed successfully".

I make it with destroy() but that isn't what I need.

Comment: What you have tried so far? post the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call [`waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) on the `Process` return by `exec()`. This will wait for the thread to end, and will return the exit value that you can test (`0` is a successful exit value, everything else is an unsuccessful exit value).

```
try {
    final Process calc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc");
    if (calc.waitFor() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Program has been closed successfully.", "Program closed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Program has been closed unsuccessfully.", "Program closed", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IO error: " + e.getMessage(), "Exception encountered", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread interrupted: " + e.getMessage(), "Exception encountered", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and call `waitFor()` on the process and when that method returns check `isAlive()` to be sure. To check whether the process was terminated normally or not you could either examine the return value of `waitFor()` or call `exitValue()`.

Comment: Calls to `isAlive()` and `exitValue()` are not needed, as `waitFor()` will wait for the process to terminate, and will return the exit value.